# I want to run a script multiple times sequentially in python

Tags: python, loops, wait, single-threaded

I have a python script which basically calls a few functions, but takes quite a while to complete. I want to be able to run this script many times on a loop.

I need the script to wait until it's previous iteration is done.

so for example;

```
for i in range(times_to_run):
    do_things(thing_variable)
```

How can I make it so that the script waits until do_things() is done, before calling it again, and iterating through the loop. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're calling an [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) function, blocking until the function returns is the default behavior.

Comment: If you want to parallelize it see this: https://github.com/niccokunzmann/maglev-wiki-pictures/blob/master/links.py#L33